# how to give individual schema access to users in apache-superset?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, analytics, apache-superset

I have searched a lot about this question, there are no concrete answers to this.
I have a AWS Redshift DB, has around 6-7 schema' with 10-12 tables in each.
and dashboards are made within schema level as well as across schema.

here's the use case:

- I have some users who needs to see only dashboards related to **"schema 1" but not "schema 2"**
- I have some other users who are looking at dashboards which are connected to **"schema 1" and as well as "schema 2"**, but m not able to find any workaround to this.

I have seen a thread saying that it's possible to give access to schema but they haven't mentioned that How.

https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/issues/5483#issuecomment-494227986

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the Superset documentation, you can not create access level on the schema but you can create access on data source level. Or you can create custom data sources and can create desired roles as per your need.

Refer: https://superset.incubator.apache.org/security.html#managing-gamma-per-data-source-access